# Excel solver could not find a feasible solution when run for the 2nd time

Tags: excel, solver

I have a solver model in Excel 2016, using Simplex LP. It runs once successfully. If I run it again without changing anything, it fails:

> error: solver could not find a feasible solution, solver can not find a point for which all constraints are satisfied.

If I close Excel and run it again, it works. What is the possible issue?